# IONIC - VirtualScroll Performance issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

So, 
I have an array of items between 0 - 2500.

I'm trying to use the virtualscroll option (as this is what I have read to handle large arrays) to improve the diabolical performance issue when displaying\scrolling through about 1300 items.

So I've done the following, but still its painful and can crash the app when scrolling.

```
 <ion-list [virtualScroll]="results" approxItemWidth="100%" approxItemHeight="45px" bufferRatio=60>
    <button ion-item   *virtualItem="let result" (click)="goToClient(result)">
      {{result.FirstName}} {{result.LastName}}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

Anyone advise what i'm doing wrong\ how to improve?

Comment: Is there any error when run app in browser? Or your list just not showing?

Comment: Nope works fine.

Comment: try to implement the ui-scroll. it will improve the performance. and app never get crash.

Comment: @D-W what is the platform you are trying this?

Comment: using IONIC 3, IOS

Comment: decrease bufferRatio, somthing changed?

Comment: have you checked it with a lower `bufferRatio` size?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the `Cordova wkWebview Engine` , it optimizes the iOS Performance issues:

**Installation Instructions**

Ensure the latest Cordova CLI is installed: (Sudo may be required)

```
npm install cordova -g
```

Ensure the ios platform has been added:

```
ionic cordova platform ls
```

If the iOS platform is not listed, run the following command:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

If the iOS platform is installed but the version is < 4.x, run the following commands:

```
ionic cordova platform update ios
ionic cordova plugin save           # creates backup of existing plugins
rm -rf ./plugins            # delete plugins directory
ionic cordova prepare               # re-install plugins compatible with cordova-ios 4.x
```

Install the WKWebViewPlugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git --save
```

**Note:**

If you already had apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine install make sure that is removed before using this version.

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

**Build the platform:**

```
ionic cordova prepare
```

**Test the app on an iOS 9 or 10 device:**

```
ionic cordova run ios
```

An easy way to verify that WKWebView has been installed on iOS is to check if window.indexedDB exists. For example:

```
if (window.indexedDB) {
   console.log("I'm in WKWebView!");
} else {
   console.log("I'm in UIWebView");
}
```

**Required Permissions**

WKWebView may not fully launch (the deviceready event may not fire) unless if the following is included in config.xml:

**config.xml**

```
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*"/>
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

here find the [Complete Instructions](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine#installation-instructions)